Video fills up all of the space (AVPlayer, UIViewControllerRepresentable, SwiftUI)
I'm trying to display video in the background. Red parts fill up all of the screen. How can I achieve, so there will be no red filling up space and the size of the view will equal content size?
// VideoPlayerUIView is a UIViewControllerRepresentable for AVPlayer
struct VideoPlayerUIView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let player: AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let controller = UIViewController()
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        
        // Set the video to fill the screen
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        playerLayer.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        controller.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}

// This is how I display it
 VideoPlayerUIView(player: player1)
          .background(.red)
 



There is a built-in VideoPlayer. Why are you not using that?

Unfortunately does not help, same thing

I never said it will help. I was just wondering if there is any reason you don't want to use VideoPlayer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78975579/unable-to-scale-up-a-video-from-edge-to-edge
